# Custom Elements data attributes not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a custom html element and pass along with its instantiation some custom data tags.  The problem is its dataset is always empty, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I'm following the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) from MDN on custom elements.. and this example does work in my browsers.. Additionally, I can successfully pass custom data tags when I add a standard img on my page, but not when I use my custom html element.

Below are my js file (defined in MyImage.js) and my html file.  Along side these is an image called small.jpg.

```js
class MyImage extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // Create a dom shadow root
    var domShadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // Create a standard img element and set its attributes.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.alt = this.dataset.name;
    img.src = this.dataset.img;
    
    // Add the image to the shadow root.
    domShadow.appendChild(img);
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('my-image', MyImage);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>myimage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="MyImage.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-image data-name="My special image name" data-img="small.jpg"></my-image>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is ur browser?

Comment: I'm trying it on Safari and Chrome (Mac) and getting the same results in both.

Comment: This is working fine for me! (Chrome 61.0.3163.100 windows )

Comment: Hm.. that's good to know.  Any insights as to why it doesn't work on Mac?  My ultimate solution will need to be compatible on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Check your browser version for support here https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1

Comment: It is Safari 11 and Chrome 62 - both listed as partial support (they don't support custom built in elements, which this is not).  However, more importantly - the example I linked to on the MDN site DOES work on my browser.. all I'm doing is a simplified version of that.. so I'm trying to figure out their custom data tags are working and mine are not.  They don't list the entire example, though.. just snippets, so I'm afraid I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet works if I change the location that the script is loaded.  If I put the script element at the end of the body, the example works fine.  See snippet below:

```js
// Create a class for the element
class MyImage extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // Create a dom shadow root
    var domShadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // Create a standard img element and set its attributes.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.alt = this.dataset.name;
    img.src = this.dataset.img;


    // Add the image to the shadow root.
    domShadow.appendChild(img);
    
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('my-image', MyImage);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>myimage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-image data-name="My special image name" data-img="small.jpg"></my-image>
       
        <script src="MyImage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now my question becomes: why?  I know that the location of a script declaration/reference will affect when it's loaded in a page, but does anyone know exactly what is happening here that is causing it to not pass the custom attributes correctly when instantiating my custom element?

Comment: Posting this as an "answer" discourages people who might answer it from looking at your question. You should either [edit] your question, or post a new one with the relevant details to focus on the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to get properties as below from DOM instantiation

```
img.alt = this.getAttribute('data-name');
img.src = this.getAttribute('data-img');
```

Comment: Thank you but that does not work either.  The my-image instance has an empty attribute set and an empty dataset (which I verify using the browser debugger).